# How to use same function for different elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

How can I use the same function to transform different elements? Can I use something like `this.target` etc?

I've got an example here wanted to transition a Box component when I clicked on the Move Box button. But now no matter which button I clicked, only the first Box will be transformed...

```
const handleChangePos = () => {
  let box = document.getElementById("box");
  box.style.transform = `translateY(-20px)`;
};

const n = 4;

function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hero</h1>
        <HeroBox>
            <Box id="box" />
            <button onClick={handleChangePos}>Move Box</button>
        </HeroBox>

        <h2>Sub Hero</h2>
        <SubHeroContainer>
        {[...Array(n)].map((e, i) => (
            <SubHeroBox key={i}>
                <Box2 id="box" />
                <button onClick={handleChangePos}>Move Box</button>
            </SubHeroBox>
        ))}
        </SubHeroContainer>
     </div>
);}
```

Live example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/6vxqlo06v3

The ideal result I want will be I clicked on the button, then it's respective Box will transform, and other Boxes won't be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this problem multiple ways, but first, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. Since you already have the `id="Box"` for the header, I would suggest generating the rest with the indices:

```
 <SubHeroContainer>
        {[...Array(n)].map((e, i) => (
            <SubHeroBox key={i}>
                <Box2 id={`box-${i}`} />
                <button onClick={() => handleChangePos(i)}>Move Box</button>
            </SubHeroBox>
        ))}
 </SubHeroContainer>
```

You can then modify `handleChangePos` to accept a parameter (the index) and find the given element:

```
const handleChangePos = (index) => {
  let box = document.getElementById(index ? `box-${index}` : "box");
  box.style.transform = `translateY(-20px)`;
};
```

To avoid passing the index you could also use `event.target.name` from the event passed by the buttons when you click them, and declare the button like `<button onClick={handleChangePos} name={i} >Move Box</button>`, but its much the same.

I would also suggest not using IDs but maintaining a list of `refs`, and modifying them based on the index. You can read more about refs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Because I do this for stateless component that's why I used ID. Refs can't be used in stateless right?

Comment: I've updated the example link's code and it works with your solution. But I can't get the second row first element to transform, when I clicked it, the first row element transformed.
I think it is because the second row first element ID is zero...
Not sure about the event.target.name way, try it but failed...would you mind to give me an example? thanks!!!

Comment: You are right, refs cannot be used with stateless components, however I would suggest using a statefull component in your case, having only small subcomponents as stateless components like `Box` and `SubHeroContainer`.

Comment: ah i got transform the 2nd row 1st item by using `let box = document.getElementById(index === undefined ? "box-main" : `box-${index}`);`

Comment: You can handle the first row similarly to the first one, you can also name it `box-0` and also use it's event handler like `()=>handleChangePos(0)`. Then you won't need the logic in the handler function to check if the index is undefined. It should work well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new component that wraps the functionality you want. With React you should never need to call `document.getElementById`

I've edited your example to create a new component that stores its offset in the component state. This fixes it for the sub boxes, but you will need to find a way to make it extendable for the main hero box too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3vn642j63m

Here is the relevant component incase that link dies:

```
class Moveable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { offset: 0 };
    this.move = this.move.bind(this);
  }
  move() {
    if (this.state.offset === 0) {
      this.setState({ offset: -20 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ offset: 0 });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return [
      <Box2 id="box" style={{transform: `translateY(${this.state.offset}px)`}} />,
      <button onClick={this.move}>Move Box</button>
    ];
  }
}
```